# To find average of data of month end date only using pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a list of company names, dates, and pe ratios.
I need to find an average of the previous 10 years data of the given date such that only month-end date is considered.

for example if I need to find average as of 31st dec, 2015..... I need to first find data of all previous month ends from 31/12/2005 to 31/12/2015. and then their average.

[sample data I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suQ7r.png)

required output:
[required output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dncl1.png)

here is what I have done soo far....

```
df = pd.read_csv('daily_valuation_ratios_cc.csv')

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df = df.set_index('date')
columns = ['pe', 'price_bv', 'mcap_ns', 'ev_ebidta']
df_mean = df.groupby('Company Name')[columns].resample('M').mean()
```

but this method is finding mean on daily basis and is showing result monthly, unlike my sample output.
i am new to pandas, pls help.

Edit:

```
df3 = df.groupby(['Company Name','year','month'])
df3.first()
```

this code works, now I just have one problem, to export dataframe to to_csv. pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dataframe has a special function called `groupby` that selects a column, and can be aggregated.

So if you were to run, `data.groupby('pe')` you would get that column.

Now if you were to tack on `.describe`, you would get the standard deviation/mean/min/ect.

Example:

```
data.groupby('pe').describe()
```

Edit: You can also use built-in aggregate functions such as .max()/.mean()/ect. with groupby().

Comment: i need a filter to find average of the month end dates only.

Comment: @jezrael can you help me this one please.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62149312/finding-10th-percentile-for-all-the-data-cumulatively